# Average color of a CIImage ... a faster method

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

I have a CIImage that is 258x258. I apply a filter `CIAreaAverage` to it, in order to get the green value of the average color of that image.

I am using this function to get that...

```
// channel 0,1,2 = red, green, blue
func averageColorOfImage (_ inputImage: CIImage, _ channel: Int) -> Double {

  let extentVector = CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.origin.x, y: inputImage.extent.origin.y, z: inputImage.extent.size.width, w: inputImage.extent.size.height)

  guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey: extentVector]) else { return 0 }
  guard let outputImage = Static.filter!.outputImage else { return 0 }

  var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
  let context = CIContext(options: [.workingColorSpace: kCFNull])
  context.render(outputImage, toBitmap: &bitmap, rowBytes: 4, bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: nil)

  return Double(bitmap[channel]) / Double(255)
}
```

This runs relatively fast but I am trying to see if there is a way to get that color fast.

I remember that Core Image has this custom "core filter" stuff.

Is there a way to do get the green value of the average color of an image using custom core filter?

Comment: Several thoughts, probably none worth anything. (1) What exactly are you trying to do? If you wish to render this in a `UIImage`, can you bypass CI entirely? (2) I've never used `CIAreaAverage`, but the output is a single pixel. Maybe use a different way to render your bitmap? (3) I don't think you want to explore creating a custom `CIKernel`. The way it processes it involves (a) eliminating a color kernel because you want "the average of the entire image" and thus (b) a general kernel means - I think - you are processing for that *image* average for every single pixel in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I'd do. (And actually do in one app to create a constant color CIImage of a specific size.

(1) Use `CIAreaAverage` to get you signal pixel value just like you are doing. But instead of using the output of the green channel to create a bitmap (which I believe is the real issue you are facing)....

(2) Use if as input for `CIConstantColorGenerator`, which will create an *infinite* sized color. Then....

(3) Use that output as input to `CICrop` and crop it to the dimensions you want.

Essentially you end up with a "sized" CIImage of a constant color of whatever you wish. In the code below, replace my input for `inputColor` with the green channel output of `CIAreaAverage` and you'll get a 640x640 CIImage of it.

```
func createNewPalette() {
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator")
    filter?.setValue(CIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4), forKey: "inputColor")
    ciPalette = filter?.outputImage
    let crop = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
    crop?.setValue(ciPalette, forKey: "inputImage")
    crop?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 640, w: 640), forKey: "inputRectangle")
    ciPaletteOriginal = crop?.outputImage
}
```

Comment: Nice trick, though it can be done in one line: `return CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4)).cropped(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 640)`. But I honestly don't see why this is answering the "How do I get the average color faster?" question...